# slow copy due to disk write issue

Tags: linux, performance

I am trying to copy a file from /backup/ folder to /backup/abc/ and it is taking a lot of time. The copy operation on performed on other server is pretty fast.

```
# df -HP
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc3       482G  351G  107G  77% /
tmpfs           4.2G   74k  4.2G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sdc1       204M   36M  157M  19% /boot
/dev/sdb3       2.0T  590G  1.3T  32% /data
/dev/sda4       2.0T  705G  1.2T  38% /backup
```

The write speed of the disks is extremely slow compared to other servers those I have.
What can be the reason behind this?

```
# hdparm -t /dev/sdc3
/dev/sdc3:
 Timing buffered disk reads:   2 MB in  3.00 seconds = 682.67 kB/sec

# hdparm -t /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1:
 Timing buffered disk reads:   2 MB in  4.10 seconds = 499.51 kB/sec

# hdparm -t /dev/sdb3
/dev/sdb3:
 Timing buffered disk reads: read(2097152) returned 4096 bytes

# hdparm -t /dev/sda4
/dev/sda4:
 Timing buffered disk reads:   4 MB in  6.10 seconds = 671.48 kB/sec
```

**Update**: More info

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3b011cfb

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda4               1      243201  1953512001   83  Linux
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000272a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *           1          26      204800   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdc2              26        1301    10240000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdc3            1301       60802   477940736   83  Linux
```

Comment: What does syslog show? Any error messages regarding disks?

Comment: The disk named /data (/dev/sdb3) is corrupt. But does it affect the performance of the other /backup disk?

Comment: Could you use `fdisk -l -u=sectors`? Just to check the proper alignment of the partitions (at least for sda). Could you also copy a big file from sdc3 to sda4 (or vice versa)? Use the command as root `sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; time cp /tmp/bigfile /backup/` (replace /tmp/bigfile by any big file on your sdc3 partition, a file bigger than 100 MB would be good). Report us the file size and the time to copy it as reported by the time command.

Comment: @shantanuo could you provide the information requested in my previous comment?

Comment: I do not have access to that server now. But the only question that I have is - can disabling write cache affect the server performance like this?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your last comment @shantanuo. Did you disable the "write cache" of your HDD? Or are you referering to my command using drop_caches? If you disabled the "write cache" of the disks (so that the disk does not use its internal read/write buffer) then of course this has an adverse effect on performance.

Comment: I have disabled write cache and I can see negative performance but the user has complained it is almost impossible to use application (mysql). Is it that bad on centOS ?

Comment: @shantanuo disabling write caching can have a non predictable effect on application depending on the "write profile" they have. So this is not depending on the OS (here CentOS) but on the type of update that the application performs. Why would you disable "write cache"? the only scenario I can think of is that your HDD are in RAID but without a battery-backed RAID controller.

Comment: We have power problem and in order to keep mysql data in tact I disabled write cache. But it turned out to be a disaster as php  application speed was affected. The disk is not behaving even after enabling the cache.

Comment: @shantanuo is a UPS not possible in your case? With the disk cache reactivated, could you provide the info asked in the 3rd comment?